# Are "dns-nameservers x.x.x.x" and "nameserver" on multiple lines the same thing?

Tags: linux, dns, resolv.conf

Does anyone know if there's any difference between this:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

and

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

To my understanding, they're the exact same thing, but I could be wrong. This is coming from /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are similar, but only `nameserver` will work in `/etc/resolv.conf`, and each DNS server must be on a line by itself. You can see the [manual page for resolv.conf(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) for what keywords are allowed in that file. A line using`dns-nameservers` will not work in this file. The file `resolv.conf` is standard on virtually all Unix systems and has been for a long time.

`dns-nameservers` is used in another (similar) context, the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, which is mainly used on Debian-based Linux systems (such as Ubuntu). Other Unix operating systems, and even other "flavors" of Linux usually do not use this file. But in this case, `nameserver` (singular) will not work, but `dns-nameservers` will. See https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration for more info on this.

Comment: Sweet! Makes perfect sense man. Thanks so much for this explanation!